# Reuse access token from MSAL in web view

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, openid, azure-ad-msal

In my iOS app I'm currently authenticating through the [MSAL iOS SDK](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc) and it's working fine. Somewhere in the app I'm also required to show a website (opened via UIWebView) that also requires the same Azure AD authentication. Since I'm already authenticated through the SDK and have an access token, is there any way to bypass authentication process in the web view?

Comment: have you solved this issue? could you share your solution?

Comment: Have you found a solution please ?

Comment: @chikos sadly, no.

Comment: @oyvindhauge u can use                                                                                              
 `var webViewParamaters : MSALWebviewParameters
 webViewParamaters.webviewType = .safariViewController`

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the following for cookie sharing:

**1. ASWebAuthenticationSession in MSAL + open URL in Safari browser**

> MSAL
>
> ```
> var webViewParamaters : MSALWebviewParameters
> webViewParamaters.webviewType = .authenticationSession
> ```
>
> WEB
>
> ```
> UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "your URL")!)
> ```

**2. SFSafariViewController in MSAL + open URL in SFSafariViewController**

> MSAL
>
> ```
>  var webViewParamaters : MSALWebviewParameters
>  webViewParamaters.webviewType = .safariViewController
> ```
>
> WEB
>
> ```
>  SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "your URL")!)
> ```

**NOTE**: WKWebView in MSAL and WKWebView to open URL will not work.

Comment: Don't think this applies anymore.

Comment: Why WKWebView in MSAL will not work to open the URL in WKWebView inside the app with cookie sync?

Comment: Also from the Organisation side Only Safari browser is supported with Intune, How can we still use the WKWebView and get around the issue?